# Injecting IL into strongly named Assembly?

Tags: .net, cil, il

I have a problem with a Library whose assembly is strongly typed and for which I don't have the source code. Thanks to Reflector I found the source of the bug, but unfortunately the class is sealed which prevents me from just subclassing it. As it refers to tons of internal methods, a simple copy/paste of the entire source also fails.

As a last resort I thought I could inject some IL into the assembly (it's a relatively simple thing, just need to add an `|| something.GetType() == typeof(System.DBNull)` to an if-statement, but I assume that the strong naming would be a problem?

Is there a way out of this or am I at the mercy of the vendor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you roundtrip the assembly using ildasm/ilasm and fix the il yourself - the strong name won't survive the roundtrip (since you don't have the key to resign it).  if it has to be in the gac, then you can create your own key and resign it with a new one.

Problem is support, the vendor will most likely not help you afterwards and going forward if you ever needed to update the assembly (say a new version comes out), you would again have to do the fix to the new version of the vendor's dll... which starts a whole domino effect of nightmares on down the road - so i would avoid changing the assembly if at all possible.

Comment: Accepting because the strong name indeed doesn't survive any tampering

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the assembly to continue to be strongly named?

If you do, does it have to have the same strong name as it had before?

You can always generate your own key pair and re-sign the assembly with your key, as opposed to the vendor's key. That will still allow you to insert the modified assembly into the gac.

One thing to be aware of, however, is that your license for the library may not allow you to redistribute modified copies.

If you need to ship the library then you are probably at the mercy of the vendor.